# A folder created by my app is missing on Marshmallow (6.0.1)

Tags: android, android-internal-storage

In my android-app I have created a folder on the internal storage of my device.
When I browse the internal storage I can see the folder and its content.
[image: Browsing through device]

When I connect the device to my pc and open the internal storage, the folder is missing. All other folders are available, but not the folder I created from my app. 
[image: Browsing through Windows-Explorer]

I tried to turn on "show invisible files" for my windows, but the folder is still missing. Any suggestions?

I tried to use MediaScannerConnection.scanFile from Vijai's answere. After this, i can see the file, but is not displayed as a directorie. Nothing happens with double click on it.

[image]

The folder itself is beeing created by my databasemanager. Its an extensionclass of the SQLiteOpenHelper-class.

```
private DatabaseManager(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); //DATABASE_NAME = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "[Name of my directorie]" + File.separator + "[Name of my db].DB";
    mContext = context;
    getWritableDatabase();
}
```

This was working fine for so long. I was able to see the directory in the past. Since my customer changed his phone to android 6.0.1, the file is no more visible.

Comment: which folder not shown in your mobile or laptop ?

Comment: the folder with the red border around is missing on my pc, but available on my device

Comment: which system u can use now in laptop??

Comment: yesssssssssssss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To scan all the files in a folder, you can build a String array containing the file paths and pass it to the mediascanner's scanFile() method.

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) {

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "yourdirectory");

    // Create empty directory and its missing parent directories
    dir.mkdirs();

    if (dir.exists())
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, buildFilePaths(dir), null, null);
}

private String[] buildFilePaths(File directory){
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList();
    for (File file : files)
        filePaths.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    return filePaths.toArray(new String[filePaths.size()]);
}
```

-----Original answer-----

You have to rescan the storage to show the directory (android does a whole system media scan at intervals or during boot)

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED) {

    File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "yourdirectory");

    // Create empty directory and its missing parent directories
    dir.mkdirs();

    if (dir.exists())
        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] {dir.toString()}, null, null);
}
```

p.s: MTP mode sucks!

Comment: I will add this to my question, i can not post pictures in the comments. There is now a file shown with the right name, but it's not a directorie. Double click on it and nothing happens.

Comment: Well, I think you're creating the directory wrong may be? Update question with the code showing the directory creation

Comment: @Olli check my updated answer. Have added code to create directory

Comment: check my updated question. The folder is beeing created automaticly by the sqliteopenhelper-class. this has worked for so long. i was always able to see and browse the folder on windows. since my customer changed his phone to android 6.0.1 it was no more visible.

Comment: If i restart the phone. The directory wiht its subdirectories and its files is visible. If i use this approach, there is a directory with the right name, but its empty. It is also not shown as a real directory (look at the updated question).

Comment: @Olli ok. I'm sorry. I did a simple search and it seems like the MediaScannerConnection's scanFile() deliberately assumes that the folder is also a "file". What I think of a work around is, create a temporary empty file in that folder (or any existing file) and scan it.

Comment: When i create a new file in one of my "missing" directories, then they show up and the file i was scanning shows up with no icon. The other files are still missing. What i figured out from other questions is, that i have to do a media scann. But when i try to do this via sendBroadcast(new Intent("android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED", Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))); i get a denial because of missing permissions. I know how to grant permissions on the fly via checkSelfPermission, but i dont know which Manifest.permission.? i should use.

Comment: Ok i can not use this permission, it is for system-apps only. The only solution was able to find is to get every directoryname and filename that should be scannend and use MediaScannerConnection.scanFile. I am not able to just pass the top directory. i have to pass every single item. I will upate my question or post an anwere when i finnished it.

Comment: @Olli you can get list of all files in the folder and send the array to scanfile() to scan all at once. I'll update the answer soon

Comment: yeah this worked for me +1. I think the scanning should be done automaticly by the android system when a new folder is being created, this should not be done by the programmer.